# have a regex match 'a-a' and 'b-b', but not 'a-b'?

Tags: javascript, regex

this is a really hard question to phrase,  but is there a way to have a regex match `'a-a'` and `'b-b'`, but not `'a-b'`? basically i want it to match with the same character either side of a middle character (such as '-') but that said character is interchangeable with other characters in a set of characters (such as `[abc]`). I'd like the solution to be not brute forced as the set of characters i have in mind is quite large, and the answer should be in javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is `/^([a-c])-\1$/`

You may reference any captured group through a `\number` syntax, where `number` is the number of your group, starting from 1.

Tests:

```js
const pattern = /^([a-c])-\1$/;

pattern.test('a-a'); // true
pattern.test('b-b'); // true
pattern.test('c-c'); // true
pattern.test('a-b'); // false
```